# validating array values in PHP

Tags: php

I have this (note that the text box is an array)

```
echo "<td><input style='width:60px' type='text' name='allocas[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two' size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
```

then in a validation code I have the following;

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    if($_POST['allocas']=='')
    {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>mikies</td></tr></table>";
    echo "Empty field";} 
    else 
    {
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>mikies</td></tr></table>";
    echo "Saved!";}
}
```

My issue is `($_POST['allocas']==''` doesn't seems to be doing the job as it doesn't validate and irrespective whether I have a value in `allocas` or not it goes to 'else' validation and prints `Saved!`.

If I change the text box from an array to a standalone text by changing the name to `name='allocas'` instead of `name='allocas[]'` then it works. So the issue is my validation of array values isn't correct and struggling to find an alternative approach. can you help?

Note : All these are not hard coded and dynamically populated. (live inside an `echo` tag)

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you make a text field an array? I've never done that so may be it has its use and it would be nice to learn about this.

Comment: Assume I get to pick a value from a drop down which carries series of numbers from a database and upon selection, you got to print xxx amount of text boxes in the UI

Comment: Thanks but i still fail to see how picking a value from a dropdown (probably a `<select>`) transform into turning a text box into an array. I mean just a good old loop could do that. Anyways, if you ever write an article about this (advantanges/disadvantanges) please consider updating this question!

Comment: Mine is actually a more complicated story. But I get your point. For me that option however doesn't work. I tried. :)

Comment: Well, at least thanks for opening my eyes to any new possibility! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `allocas[]` as the field name forces PHP to treat that as a potentially multi-valued field, and it will create an array. This array will be created regardless of how many actual fields come in with that name.

When you do

```
$_POST['allocas'] == ''
```

you're actually comparing an ARRAY to a string. Since that comparison makes no sense, PHP will type-cast the array to the raw string `Array` (literally the letters `A`, `r`, `r`, etc...), which evaluates to false.

You need to count how many values are in the array, then check those individual values for "emptiness", e.g.

```
if (count($_POST['allocas']) > 0) {
   ... got some values
   foreach($_POST['allocas'] as $value) {
      ... test $value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
name='allocas[]'
```

to

```
name='allocas'
```

in your form/input.

Answer (score 0):

If your input field is an "array" you can't check it afterwards like a string.

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    if(count($_POST['allocas']) == 0)
    {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>mikies</td></tr></table>";
        echo "Empty field";
    } else 
    {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>mikies</td></tr></table>";
        echo "Saved!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try whether the value is empty try follwing

```
if (empty($_POST['allocas']))
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is a value for something in PHP, you can use the `empty` function.  I would also recommend checking that the value is indeed an array (you never know what people will do to your form)

```
if(isset($_POST['allocas']) && is_array($_POST['allocas']) && !empty($_POST['allocas'])) {
    //Yay! Something is here
}
```

References

[is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over each of the POST values and validate each:

```
// Sanity check
if(is_array($_POST['allocas'])) {
  foreach($_POST['allocas'] as $oneTextFieldsValue) {
    // Validate $oneTextFieldsValue...
  }
}
```